ArcGIS REST Map Services Data Query using geometry in Python
I am attempting to access ArcGIS Map Services and query a dataset to only return records that intersect the boundary of a custom geometry I created. I have queried and downloaded data before using this script, but never using geometry. Do i simply add my geometry_json to the Where clause?
#My geometry (a simply polygon)

geometry_json = {
  "geometryType" : "esriGeometryPolygon",
  "spatialReference" : {
    "wkid" : 4326,
    "latestWkid" : 4326
  },
  "features" : [{
      "geometry":{
      "curveRings":[
          [[-123.77335021899995,49.353870065000081],{"a":[[-123.77335021899995,49.353870065000081],[-123.88831213030559,49.338864996255367],0,1]}]]}}]
}

The script to access and download the data
import arcpy  # Import the arcpy module, which provides access to ArcGIS functionality.
import urllib.request  # Import the urllib.request module to work with URLs.
import json  # Import the json module for JSON data handling.

# Setup
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True 
baseURL = r"https://gisp.dfo-mpo.gc.ca/arcgis/rest/services/FGP/MSDI_Dynamic_Current_Layer/MapServer/0"  # Base URL
fields = "*"  # Return all fields
outdata = r"out/path"  #output location

# Get record extract limit
urlstring = baseURL + "?f=json"  # Construct the URL to request JSON metadata from the service.
j = urllib.request.urlopen(urlstring)  # Open the URL and get the response.
js = json.load(j)  # Load the JSON response into a Python dictionary.
maxrc = int(js["maxRecordCount"])  # Extract the maximum record count from the JSON response.
print ("Record extract limit: %s" % maxrc)  # Print the maximum record count.

# Get object ids of features
where = "1=1" # Define a where clause to retrieve all records.
urlstring = baseURL + "/query?where={}&returnIdsOnly=true&f=json".format(where)  # Construct the URL to request object IDs.
j = urllib.request.urlopen(urlstring)  # Open the URL and get the response.
js = json.load(j)  # Load the JSON response into a Python dictionary.
idfield = js["objectIdFieldName"]  # Extract the name of the object ID field.
idlist = js["objectIds"]  # Extract the list of object IDs.
idlist.sort()  # Sort the list of object IDs.
numrec = len(idlist)  # Get the number of records.
print ("Number of target records: %s" % numrec)  # Print the number of records.

# Gather features
print ("Gathering records...")  # Print a message indicating feature gathering.
fs = dict()  # Create an empty dictionary to store features.
for i in range(0, numrec, maxrc):  # Loop over the object IDs in chunks based on the maximum record count.
  torec = i + (maxrc - 1)  # Calculate the end index of the chunk.
  if torec > numrec:  # Adjust the end index if it exceeds the number of records.
    torec = numrec - 1
  fromid = idlist[i]  # Get the starting object ID of the chunk.
  toid = idlist[torec]  # Get the ending object ID of the chunk.
  where = "{} >= {} and {} <= {}".format(idfield, fromid, idfield, toid)  # Define a where clause for the chunk.
  print ("  {}".format(where))  # Print the where clause.
  urlstring = baseURL + "/query?where={}&returnGeometry=true&outFields={}&f=json".format(where,fields)  # Construct the URL to request features.
  fs[i] = arcpy.FeatureSet()  # Create a new empty FeatureSet object.
  fs[i].load(urlstring)  # Load features from the URL into the FeatureSet.

# Save features
print ("Saving features...")  # Print a message indicating feature saving.
fslist = []  # Create an empty list to store FeatureSets.
for key,value in fs.items():  # Iterate over the dictionary of FeatureSets.
  fslist.append(value)  # Append each FeatureSet to the list.
arcpy.Merge_management(fslist, outdata)  # Merge all FeatureSets into a single feature class at the specified output location.
print ("Done!")  # Print a message indicating completion.


See 'geometry' parameter in the ArcGIS REST APIs Query operation doc: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/query-map-service-layer-.htm

Thanks for your comment. I've actually seen this documentation but was not quite sure how to pass the geometry to the where clause.

You don't pass the geometry in the where clause, it's a separate parameter (see the examples at the bottom of the documentation).

When interacting with the ArcGIS REST API, you can save yourself a lot of time/effort/error handling by using the arcgis package in addition to arcpy.
arcpy is your interface for ArcMap/ArcGIS Pro whereas arcgis is your interface for the ArcGIS REST API (whether ArcGIS Online or ArcGIS Enterprise).
Here's a brief example:
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.geometry.filters import intersects

gis = GIS("pro")

geometry = {
    "rings" : [[
        [-117.751322686672, 34.1209151280806], 
        [-117.751320675015, 34.1209101319963], 
        [-117.751322686672, 34.1209068012733], 
        [-117.751326709986, 34.1209056910323], 
        [-117.751330733299, 34.1209062461528], 
        [-117.751333415508, 34.1209095768758], 
        [-117.751331403852, 34.1209151280806], 
        [-117.751327380538, 34.1209173485624], 
        [-117.751322686672, 34.1209151280806]
    ]]
}

item = gis.content.get("<item_id>")
layer = item.layers[<layer_id>]
features = layer.query(where="1=1", geometry_filter=intersects(geometry, 4326))

If using ArcGIS Pro's Python env, you can auth the GIS object using the active portal in ArcGIS Pro via gis = GIS("pro"). For other sign-in options, see the doc.
If you really don't want to use the arcgis package, see the geometry parameter for the ArcGIS REST APIs Map Service Query operation.

Thanks for this, it definitely seems a lot simpler than what i'm doing. Is there any documentation I can read on this? is the item_id the service item id or the url? How do i define an output dir?
